# How to Upload image from iOS app to server using REST?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

```
I want to upload image from iOS app. and store into server's folder.
```

I am     using spring as a controller. how to achieve this functionality.
 I have     tried Base64 decoder and encoder but it allowed only small image. so     any other idea or suggestion. I will be really thankful.

```
@RequestMapping(value="Customer/uploadImage.htm",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    String filePath = HomeAppUtil.getPathForImage();
    System.out.println("filepath "+filePath);
    String img = "testfile.jpeg";
    try {
        // parses the request's content to extract file data
        if(file.getSize() !=0){
            System.out.println("in if");
            File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, img);
            System.out.println("in if 1");
            if (!fileToCreate.exists()) {
                System.out.println("in if 2");
                FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(fileToCreate, file.getBytes());
                System.out.println("in if 3");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }


    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.put("updated or fialed!!");

    return jsonArray.toString();
}
```

This is my controller. please guide me.

Comment: POST as `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Thanks but how to get that image in controller and store at server's folder.

Comment: http:/localhost:8080/www.mydomain.com/myproject/Customer/uploadImage.htm    when i test in Post man its give me an 404 bad request. please help me.

Comment: You can't just POST to something like `http:/localhost:8080/www.mydomain.com/myproject/Customer/uploadImage.htm` - this needs to be mapped as a REST endpoint. Do you have any @POST annotations at your `uploadImage()` method? I suggest you work through `https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/` and see if you get this working.

Comment: Thanks giving your time. I do not use @POST annotation in that method. and  image will upload from iOS app and i need to store at server using spring controller. any other idea if you have please guide. - Johannes Jander

Comment: I have updated my question now i need source for iOS what i have to write to to perfect upload. I have check above code in POST man its working fine. now http:/localhost:8080/www.mydomain.com/myproject/Customer/uploadImage.htm this will work. but now i want to call this api from iOS. how can i do this? Thanks. @JohannesJander